# Issues on Centos Repo

Tags: linux, centos, yum

Can someone help me to solve the below problem. I'm not able to install any software with yum.

**Error Displayed**

```
# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. $releasever is not a valid release or hasnt been released yet/
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/i386/$releasever/base/mirrorlist.txt
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

Thanks for the support

Thanks,

Comment: Could you give your `/etc/yum.conf` content?

Answer (score 2):

The value of `$releasever` is determined by taking the `distroverpkg` configuration value, which may be set in `yum.conf` but would normally be left at the default value, and then checking to see what version of that package is installed.

By default that will be the `redhat-release` release package, so check what version of that you have installed, and that nobody has set `distroverpkg` to something silly in `yum.conf`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information.

Here's what I have on my yum.conf. The distroverpkg=centos-release there is no version specified for it. Can you help me out..

 cat /etc/yum.conf
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=16&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release

Thanks,

Comment: @JimmyReel Welcome to Server Fault. You should edit your question with requested information, rather than adding it to comments, because it may not be noticed here and is difficult to read anyway.

Comment: @JimmyReel Your next step is to use `rpm -q centos-release` to see what version of that package you have installed.

Comment: @TomH Thanks, Here's what I get when I do [root@server1 ~]# rpm -q centos-release
package centos-release is not installed.

Comment: Well that's your problem - you need to install that so that `yum` can figure out the value for `$releasever`.

Answer (score 0):

First use the command to check the packages like yum, rpm, python are installed or not.

*rpm -q centos-release yum rpm python python-elementtree rpm-python yum-metadata-parser*

In result column seek the packages yum and rpm and check whether its installed or not.
If not use the command to install the yum rpm and other python which is mandatory for yum and rpm

*yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=c6-media install centos-release yum rpm python python-elementtree rpm-python yum-metadata-parser*

c6 or c5 used according to os version